# Issue about converting from char array to string - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, challenge-response

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string vet[10], aux;
    std::vector<char> name;
    int count=0, sum=0; 

    while (count<10) {
        getline(cin, aux);

        for (int i=0; i<aux.length(); i++)  name.push_back(aux[i]);

        for (int i=0; i<name.size(); i++) {
            name[i] = tolower(name[i]);                                 //para garantir que todos os caracteres estão em minúsculo  
            if (name[i] > 96 && name[i] < 123 && name[i] == 32)         //faixa de decimais das letras minúsculas e espaço em caso de nome composto
                sum += name[i];
        }

        char v[name.size()];                                            //vetor auxiliar criado para realizar a conversão de vetor de char para string

        for (int i=0; i<name.size(); i++)   {
            v[i] = name[i];
        }

        while (vet[sum%10] != "\0")                                     //para evitar colisão
            sum++;

        vet[sum%10] = (string) v;                                       //conversão para string e => K mod m = K % m em C++
        cout << vet[sum%10] << endl;
        count++;
        sum = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<name.size(); i++)   v[i] = '\0';

        name.clear();
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)    cout << vet[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code is using the Hashing concept to store names inside of an array.

My question is:

> Everytime that I try to insert a name with 8, 16 or 24 characters,
>   while converting from char array to string, the compiler always put
>   another 3 characters in front of them. If I try a name with 9, 17 or
>   25 characters, the compiler always put another 2 characters in front
>   of them. And if I try a name with 10, 18 or 26 characters, the
>   compiler always put another character in front of them.
>
> Why does it happens? Is there a way to prevent it?

I need all the names to be exactly (but in lower case) as they were inserted on the input, but sorted according to the Hashing logic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: FYI: `char v[name.size()];` is not standard C++ when the array size is not a constant expression.

Comment: The condition of the if statement in line 19 will never be true. Maybe changing the last && with an || but I don't get your intent

Comment: @Bob__ Yea, it is ||. Hahaha The idea is to accept only lower case characters and space (32 on ascii table).

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for answering. I'll check it out.

Comment: **To others reading this**: You guys totally discourage people to ask on SO when unvoting questions like this. I see no problem with my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
char v[name.size()];
```

As it was pointed out this is not standard C++ ...

Regardless, you can fix it like:

```
std::string v;    
v.resize(name.size());
```

More or less it has the same effect as your char array, except that it does not use a char array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Note that `v` is totally redundant and you may just throw every mention of it away and just say `vet[sum%10] = name;`.

Comment: I get this error when using directly vet[sum%10] = name: 

`[Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'std::vector<char>')`

Comment: I am fairly certain you want to use `resize` not `reserve`.  `reserve` just allocates memory.  It does not affect the size at all: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a0c087c89bbcd85

Comment: @NathanOliver Excellent catch! Thanks for fixing the type! ... eee typo .

Comment: @fritzone No problem.  Half the time I mess it up myself with the similar naming.